# Dictionary of lists using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a string (which I treat as a list of chars) and I'm trying via dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary with the keys of every char in the string and the values as a list of the indexes in which it appeared.

For example:

```
pattern = "abcdabccb"
```

desired dictionary:

```
{'a' : [0,4], 'b' : [1,5,8], 'c':[2,6,7], 'd':[3]}
```

Best try so far:

```
{pattern[i]: [i] for i in range(0, len(pattern)) if pattern[i] != '_'}
```

returns only the last index where the char appeared.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would be *dictionary* comprehension

Comment: as you can see I'm using it, still doesn't work

Comment: In any case, doing this with a dictionary comprehension forces you to do something inefficient, like `{c:[i for i,e in enumerate(pattern) if e == c] for c in set(pattern)}`. Just use the normal grouping idiom.

Comment: why can't i accept your answer? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fun question. You'll need a list-comprehension within a dict-comprehension:

```py
>>> p = "abcdabccb"; # pattern
>>> {c: [i for i in range(len(p)) if p[i] == c] for c in p}
{'a': [0, 4], 'b': [1, 5, 8], 'c': [2, 6, 7], 'd': [3]}
>>>
```

**In plain words, here's what the comprehension says**:
Compose a dictionary by iterating over every character `c` in the pattern `p`. Use each `c` as the key, and let the corresponding value be  the list of such indices `i` in `p`, where `p[i] == c`.

Instead of `for c in p`, you may use `for c in set(p)` to iterate over each character just once.

As @quamrana points out, you can always use a loop. Here, a loop would be far more readable. But for honing your dict-comprehension chops, this is a pretty good practice problem.

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary comprehension should be used where `map` or `filter` might have been used. The `dict` that you want is a summary of the input string.

You just need to fall back on a plain for loop:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

pattern = "abcdabccb"
summary = defaultdict(list)

for idx,c in enumerate(pattern):
    summary[c].append(idx)
```

Output as required